How do I make 2D movement in Unity?
I am making a 2d shooter game and I am working on the movement code. When I run the game, and press WASD the player doesn't stop when I let go of a key.
I tried using Input.GetKeyDown("w") and Input.GetKey("w") but nothing works. I haven't been using Unity or C# for a long time and am a complete rookie. Here is my code:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Rigidbody2D rigidBody;
    public int speed = 10;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("w")) 
        {
            rigidBody.velocity = Vector2.up * speed;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("a")) 
        {
            rigidBody.velocity = Vector2.left * speed;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("d")) 
        {
            rigidBody.velocity = Vector2.right * speed;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("s")) 
        {
            rigidBody.velocity = Vector2.down * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
}


well, depending on the settings, youve set a velocity eg go 30mph left, and you never tell it to not..

You'll need something that actually slows down the player, so either or both of the drag of the player rigidbody or friction of the ground material.

Here's a solution:
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float speed = 10f;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector2 movement = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        rb.velocity = movement * speed;
    }
}

This uses Input.GetAxis() for better movem and stop if keys are released. Adjust speed as needed.

Is this the only code I need or do I need if statements?
